# need help moving pieces within chess

Tags: python, tkinter

Overall i have the chess board being created and the pieces being placed onto it and i have been doing this using tkinter specifically, my issue lies in the fact that I have created a dict called pieces and I have got a function which calls the mouse position however i cannot get the dict to return if any piece is on the space:

```
mousex = 0
mousey = 0
class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=64, color1="white", color2="gray"):
        '''size is the size of a square, in pixels'''

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}
        self.imageref ={}

        canvas_width = columns * size
        canvas_height = rows * size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # this binding will cause a refresh if the user interactively
        # changes the window size
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.refresh)
#this is how i created the pieces in the first place
    def addpiece(self, name, image, row, column):
        '''Add a piece to the playing board'''
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image, tags=(name, "piece"), anchor="c")
        self.placepiece(name, row, column)

#this allows me to move specific pieces
    def placepiece(self, name, row, column):
        '''Place a piece at the given row/column'''
        self.pieces[name] = (row, column)
        x0 = (column * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        y0 = (row * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        self.canvas.coords(name, x0, y0)

#this sets up the board
    def refresh(self, event):
        '''Redraw the board, possibly in response to window being resized'''
        xsize = int((event.width-1) / self.columns)
        ysize = int((event.height-1) / self.rows)
        self.size = min(xsize, ysize)
        self.canvas.delete("square")
        color = self.color2
        for row in range(self.rows):
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x1 = (col * self.size)
                y1 = (row * self.size)
                x2 = x1 + self.size
                y2 = y1 + self.size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
                color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
        for name in self.pieces:
            self.placepiece(name, self.pieces[name][0], self.pieces[name][1])
        self.canvas.tag_raise("piece")
        self.canvas.tag_lower("square")

#this finds where the mouse is and returns it also this is where im trying to get the dict bit to work
    def callback(self, event):
        print ("clicked at", int(event.x/64), int(event.y/64))
        x1 = int(event.x/64)
        y1 = int(event.y/64)
        pieces = self.pieces
        print(pieces)
        for x0, y0 in pieces.items():    
            if x0 == x1 and y0 == y1:
                print(pieces)

        return int(event.y/64), int(event.x/64)

#this is where all the pieces get created the first time and placed on the board
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    board = GameBoard(root)
    board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
    #bishops
    bishopb = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/bishopb.png')
    board.addpiece("bishopb1",bishopb, 0,2)
    bishopw = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/bishopw.png')
    board.addpiece("bishopw1",bishopw, 7,2)
    board.addpiece("bishopb2",bishopb, 0,5)
    board.addpiece("bishopw2",bishopw, 7,5)
    #kings
    kingb = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/kingb.png')
    kingw = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/kingw.png')
    board.addpiece("kingb",kingb, 0,4)
    board.addpiece("kingw",kingw, 7,4)
    #queens
    queenb = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/queenb.png')
    queenw = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/queenw.png')
    board.addpiece("queenb",queenb, 0,3)
    board.addpiece("queenw",queenw, 7,3)
    #kinghts
    knightb = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/knightb.png')
    knightw = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/knightw.png')
    board.addpiece("knightb1",knightb, 0,1)
    board.addpiece("knightw1",knightw, 7,1)
    board.addpiece("knightb2",knightb, 0,6)
    board.addpiece("knightw2",knightw, 7,6)
    #rooks
    rookb = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/rookb.png')
    rookw = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/rookw.png')
    board.addpiece("rookb1",rookb, 0,0)
    board.addpiece("rookw1",rookw, 7,0)
    board.addpiece("rookb2",rookb, 0,7)
    board.addpiece("rookw2",rookw, 7,7)
    #pawns
    pawnb = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/pawnb.png')
    pawnw = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/comp coursework/pawnw.png')
    board.addpiece("pawn1b",pawnb, 1,0)
    board.addpiece("pawn2b",pawnb, 1,1)
    board.addpiece("pawn3b",pawnb, 1,2)
    board.addpiece("pawn4b",pawnb, 1,3)
    board.addpiece("pawn5b",pawnb, 1,4)
    board.addpiece("pawn6b",pawnb, 1,5)
    board.addpiece("pawn7b",pawnb, 1,6)
    board.addpiece("pawn8b",pawnb, 1,7)
    board.addpiece("pawn1w",pawnw, 6,0)
    board.addpiece("pawn2w",pawnw, 6,1)
    board.addpiece("pawn3w",pawnw, 6,2)
    board.addpiece("pawn4w",pawnw, 6,3)
    board.addpiece("pawn5w",pawnw, 6,4)
    board.addpiece("pawn6w",pawnw, 6,5)
    board.addpiece("pawn7w",pawnw, 6,6)
    board.addpiece("pawn8w",pawnw, 6,7)

    board.placepiece("bishopb1",4,4)

    root.bind("<Button-1>", board.callback)

    #board.placepiece("pawn8w",)




    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Firstly, what is your question?

Comment: @josoler this site is about resolving problems with error messages in code. "computer programming" is too broad for this site.

Comment: callbacks used in `bind(..)`, `tk.Button(command=)`, `root.after()` are executed by `mainloop()` and it doesn't know what to do with returned values. You have to assign values to global variable and later get values from this variable. Or use these values directly in callback to move pieces. Or use `after()` in `callback` to run function which will use values from variable and it will not block `mainloop()`

Comment: if you use class then you can assign these values to `self.variables` instead of using global variables.

Comment: You are looping over `pieces` in the wrong way. It should be: `for name, (x0, y0) in pieces.items():`. However, I don't think the lookup will work correctly, because `pieces` contains `(row, column)` values, not `(x, y)` values.